# Composite/template stopped working inside a jar in Maven Project

Tags: maven, jar

I have some composites that will be used in other projects, in the developing time I used to test it in a dynamic web project created inside Eclipse IDE an then put its .jar in the lib folder

The .jar was package like this:

```
MyComponentProject
 |-- META-INF
 |    |-- resources
 |    |    `-- 
 |    |         |-- comp
 |    |         |    `-- someComposite.xhtml
 |    |         |-- template
 |    |         |    `-- someTemplate.xhtml
 |    |         |
 |    |-- faces-config.xml
 |    `-- MANIFEST.MF
```

and here an teste page:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:libcomp="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comp"
                xmlns:libcompAP="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comp_ap"
                template="/templates/template_blank.xhtml">


   <ui:define name="inc_act">
        <ui:include src="/comp/compActions.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>
```

It was working fine in this way but now I have to make a REAL test project using Maven.

The new project was created and was working fine in the first run, but as I started putting more composites in the main test page I started getting the following error from one of the composites:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /index.xhtml @157,32 <libcomp:compActions>
  Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/comp,
    but no tag was defined for name: compActions
```

At first I thought I just need to take it out to get everything working again but when I did it I started getting an error from the template:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException:
  /index.xhtml @8,61 <ui:composition template="/templates/template_blank.xhtml">
    Invalid path : /templates/template_blank.xhtml
```

I don't know what is going on...the template is in the same place always had. I can't figure out why it worked for a while and then now it stoped finding the template....and now I can't get it working again!

Any thought about what could it be?

I put the .jar again in a dynamic web project and it works, so I don't think it is a bad package problem at all.

I'm using JAVA 7, JBoss EAP 6.3, JSF 2.1 and Primefaces 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what happened and came back to share, might be useful to someone else...

I figure out that the problem only appears when "MyComponentProject" is opnened in my Eclipse worksoace, in order to get it working again I just need to close "MyComponentProject" project.

I dont know an explanation for its cause, the problem first happened when I noticed a problem and get the project opnened again to make a debug and then everything screwed up.